# saving my graphic drawing panel as png or jpg image format

Tags: c#, panel, graphic

I make a graphic drawing panel [my own paint program] and I want save my own drawing. This is my all code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace pezeshk
{
    public partial class pen : Form
    {
        private SolidBrush myBrush;
        private Graphics myGraphics;
        private bool isDrawing = false;
        public pen()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myBrush = new SolidBrush(panel2.BackColor);
            myGraphics = panel1.CreateGraphics();

        }

        private void panel2_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                panel2.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
                myBrush.Color = panel2.BackColor;  
            }
        }

        private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isDrawing = true;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isDrawing = false;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isDrawing == true)
            {
                myGraphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, e.X, e.Y, trackBar1.Value, trackBar1.Value);
            }
        }


}
```

Answer (score -2):

for everyone that need this code
this code works [thx to @Taw]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace pezeshk
{
    public partial class pen : Form
    {
        private SolidBrush myBrush;
        private Pen myPen;
        private Graphics myGraphics;
        private bool isDrawing = false;
        public pen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myPen = new Pen(Color.ForestGreen);
            myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkSlateBlue);
        }
        void panel1_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (rb_pen.Checked)
            {
                if (points.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawCurve(myPen, points.ToArray());
                foreach (List<Point> lp in curves)
                    if (lp.Count > 1)
                        e.Graphics.DrawCurve(myPen, lp.ToArray());


            }
        }
        private void pen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myBrush = new SolidBrush(panel2.BackColor);
            myGraphics = panel1.CreateGraphics();


        }

        private void panel2_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                panel2.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
                myBrush.Color = panel2.BackColor;
            }
        }
        Point mDown = Point.Empty;
        private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mDown = e.Location;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (rb_pen.Checked)
            {
                if (points.Count > 1) curves.Add(points.ToList());  // copy!!
                points.Clear();
                panel1.Invalidate();
            }


            panel1.Invalidate();
        }
        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {

                if (rb_pen.Checked)
                {
                    points.Add(e.Location);

                }
                panel1.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        List<Rectangle> circles = new List<Rectangle>();
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
        List<List<Point>> curves = new List<List<Point>>();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string somefolder = "D:\\"; using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.ClientSize.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height))
            {
                panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.ClientRectangle); bmp.Save(somefolder + panel1.Name + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            } 
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            curves.Clear(); points.Clear(); panel1.Invalidate();
        }

    }
    class DrawPanel : Panel
    {
        public DrawPanel() { DoubleBuffered = true; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Warning: The code contains a superflous and nonsencical CreateGraphics!

Comment: @TaW i need to resolve a issue to this program
how can i put a button that when i click on button the mouse[pen] get at first line in drawing panel to write something from firstline so easy!!!
i hope you understand